# Is an environment card a villain target?

Tags: sentinels-of-the-multiverse

We've got Villainous Weaponry in play as our Environment, and my friend has Demoralization, which lets him deal one damage to each "villain target". Villainous Weaponry has HP, and it's not a hero; does it take damage?

Comment: Which Environment deck is Villainous Weaponry from?

Comment: The mars environment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No.**

I found the clarifications document here: http://www.spiffworld.com/sotm/files/sotm_rules_and_clarifications.pdf

It reads, in part:

> What constitutes a Hero or Villain or Environment Target?
>
> Any card with hp on it is a target, and the type of deck it came from determines
> what kind of a target it is. for example, the “Enraged T-Rex” is an Environment
> card since it comes from the Environment deck, and because it has hp, it is a
> target. Therefore, it is an Environment Target. Same with a Villain card like
> “Blade Battalion”; it is a villain card because it comes from the Villain deck, and
> because it has hp, it is a target, so it’s a Villain Target. likewise, “Decoy
> Projection” is a Hero card from a Hero deck which has hp, and so is a Hero
> Target.

So Villainous Weaponry is an *environment target*, not a *villain target*.